# Построить несколько последовательностей чисел внутри одного цикла while

Tags: java, while

Необходимо построить цикл, который выводит в консоль две последовательности чисел - от 200000 до 210000 и от 220000 до 235000. Шаг увеличения в обоих случаях 1000.

```
int i = 200000;
    int step = 1000;
    while ( i < 211000)
    {
        System.out.println("№ " + i);
        i += step;

    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    int j = 220000;
    int stepNext = 1000;
    while ( j < 236000)
    {
        System.out.println("№ " + j);
        j += stepNext;введите сюда код
```

Итоговая задача - свести два цикла в один так, чтобы обе последовательности вывелись в консоль. Однако, все попытки приводят к ошибочному результату, а условия в цикле частично игнорируются.

Пример ошибочного цикла:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 200000;
    int j = 220000;
    int step = 1000;
    int stepNext = 1000;

    while (j < 236000 || i < 211000) {
        System.out.println("№ " + i);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("№ " + j);
        j += stepNext;
        i += step;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (j < 235000 || i < 210000) {
  if (i < 210000) {
    System.out.println("№ " + i);
    i += step;
  }
  if (j < 235000) {
    System.out.println("№ " + j);
    j += step;
  }
  System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
У вас чётко не описано, что требуется сделать. Просто объединить в один цикл обе последовательности или сделать перемежающийся вывод элементов каждой последовательности. 
int i = 200000;
int step = 1000;
int pitfall=210000
int jump = 220000-210000;
int final = 235000;

while ( i <=final)
{
    System.out.println("№ " + i);
    if(i==pitfall) 
               i += jump;
    i += step;    
}
```